# Run a jQuery script from resource file of UserControl to the Client's Script Manager

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a User Control that have a global resource with a string value that is jQuery script.
I want to run this script in client side,
the scenario in my mind (actually in my project manager mind) is that 
1-we need a http handler for pass value from resource to client
2-we need to check: is any script manager defined in client, if not throw an exception,
we find this script manager by move in the parents of the user control until find page or master page, so search the controls of the page(or master page) and find script manager
3-we need a way for run the mentioned script to this script manager

do you have any idea for this implementation? how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's need to force clients to add **server's httphandler helper** to webConfig of owns.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a script manager?
is it possible solution for your needs?

javascript part :

```
function RunJS(fn) {
    eval(fn);
}

function getJS() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld',
        contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            RunJS(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("error");
        }

    });
}
```

html part :

```
<input type="button" value="Get & Run JS" onclick="getJS();" />
```

web method part :

```
[WebMethod]
public void HelloWorld()
{
    Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Context.Response.Write("alert('Hello world');");
    Context.Response.End();
}
```